# Android adding custom view dynamically

Tags: android

I' m trying to add my custom PostLayout class, it adds first one but after that it crashes with this error;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

    FragmentPostLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.HomeFragmentGenerateLayout);
    PostLayout postlayout = new PostLayout(context);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        FragmentPostLayout.addView(postlayout, i - 1);//where it crashes when i=1
```

Comment: try removing the second parameter of addView (meaning use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View) )  . It seems you try to put it as the last view anyway. Try calling just : FragmentPostLayout.addView(postlayout);

Comment: still have the same error.

Comment: Oh, I know what's wrong: you add the same view. If you wish to add multiple views, you have to create multiple views. the "new PostLayout" is supposed to be inside the loop, and not outside of it.

Comment: Yes, you are right thanks! @androiddeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually is caused because you're adding a view that is already on the screen.

On the first loop of your iteration you add the PostLayout, and on the second you try re-adding it - and that's why the loop crashes when the index is 1.

Try creating a new post layout every time:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    MyView view = new MyView(context);
    ParentView.addView(view);
```

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks!